# Select-String not working in winpe powershell 4 but OK on win7

Tags: powershell, winpe, select-string

The following code will not work in winpe running PS 4 but will on 7...

```
$handler_Find_Click= 
{
$textbox1.Items.Clear();

Select-String -AllMatches -Path "x:\Scripts\PowerShell\Hosp.txt" -pattern ($HospInput.Text) | Select-Object -expand line | ForEach-Object {$textbox1.Items.Add($_)}
}
```

if i click the form button in win7 it shows the matched contents of the file in a textbox. In winpe it shows nothing on button click - but gives no errors.

SOLVED

The input box is not being recognized as i write-host the $Hospinput value when the form closes and its always this in winpe

System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:

but not in win7

i have actually solved it. it was this.

i have another submit button in the code which worked fine on click - to close the form etc.

this submit button calls like so :

```
$button.add_click({ do something here })
```

the search button was calling a variable which had the execute code in like this..

```
$find.add_click($handler_Find_Click)
```

Then i had

```
$handler_find_click={ do something here }
```

winpe does not like calling a variable to execute on click - as soon as i changed to this - it worked - so removing the $handler_find_click variable altogether.

```
$find.add_click({ do something here })
```

Comment: How did you find out that your problem in this peace of code?

Comment: I am assuming - as the issue is only when i click the search button. the rest of the form is fine. Plus i had to change the code to get it working in win7 and it was this line - in win7 it was working intermittently - i have another question which was answered. I am sure its this part of the code

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370187/select-string-issue-working-intermittently/41370250?noredirect=1#comment69943416_41370250)

Comment: ["*StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question ...*"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Does the click handler work? Is the X:\ drive accessible? Does the $hospInput have the value you expect it to have? What PS version is Win 7 running? Is it the same match pattern both times ? Do you escape the regex match pattern?

Comment: the X drive is accesible... the click handler works fine in win7, yes the same pattern is matching in all tests, PS version is 4 in both winpe and win7,

Comment: in win7 the value of the input is writing to the host as - System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: win                                                 ( i use 'win' as my test this displays all items in Hosp.txt that have win in the line. )  - in winpe this value is blank.... and not sure why